# Finding rational solutions to norm equations

Tags: number-theory

Given a number field $K$ and some integer $n$, do we know of an efficient algorithm for finding an element of $K$ that has (absolute) field norm $n$ (assuming one exists)? I am aware of a lot of research on finding integer solutions to such an equation, but I am concerned with rational solutions. The element of norm $n$ need not be an algebraic integer.

Comment: Can yu post the equations(s) you are trying to solve?

Comment: There aren't particular equations I am trying to solve. I am just wondering if a general method is known. As an example, we could adjoin some square roots of large square-free numbers that are 1 mod 8 to the rationals and try to find a field element of norm 2.